# Multidex obfuscation issue when I upgrade gradle version from 5.4.1 to 6.5

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I am facing a strange issue when I upgrade my project gradle version from 5.4.1 to 6.5. I have minifyEnabled to true and also R8 is enabled for code obfuscation. The same code which runs with 5.4.1 , crashes when I upgrade it to 6.5.1

Few of the classes are missing from final apk when using 6.5.1. I have to manually specify the keep option certain class from being obfuscated which was not the case when I was using 5.4.1.

Is there a better option to prevent the classes from being not added to the final apk? Since adding most of the classes to proguard rules doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Show proguard and let us inform which part not working

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya there is no change in proguard. I just upgraded gradle version to 6.5.1 and i see crashes dues to class missing in final apk